# Opposite of Differences

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to add the successive the elements of a list. As we know the operator "Differences" performs the difference of the successive elements of a list. Is there a function which performs the opposite job of "differences" in mathematica?

Comment: [Using `FoldList` as an inverse of `Differences`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0wgnmae-hz4).

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. Its a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part.

Comment: Why have you not accepted answers in any of your 8 questions? Voting and accepting is central to the SE model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how good/bad content gets sorted, helpful users get reputation and privileges.

Answer (score 15):

I interpret "opposite" to mean the inverse operation.  Just like with differentiation and antidifferentiation, the inverse of `Differences` is defined up to a constant and is given by [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html):

```
list = {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3};
diff = Differences[list]                (* note its length is one shorter *)
Accumulate[diff]                        (* ...and so is the length here *)
Accumulate[Prepend[diff, First[list]]]  (* the real inverse: include the starting point *)
(*
  {2, 1, 2, 0, -4}
  {2, 3, 5, 5, 1}
  {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3}
*)
```

The last command is like $f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(x)\;dx$, where the starting value is included.

Answer (score 7):

`ListConvolve[]`/`ListCorrelate[]` do the job:

```
ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3}]
   {6, 9, 12, 14, 10}
```

Answer (score 6):

Can be done with `Plus` and `Partition`:

```
data = {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3};
Plus @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]
```

> {6, 9, 12, 14, 10}

Comment: Just so it is equivalent to `Differences` you can define it in functional form as `sums = Plus @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &`

Answer (score 6):

There's also the MovingAverage (of length 2),

```
2 MovingAverage[{2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3}, 2]

{6, 9, 12, 14, 10}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3};
```

There have been two interpretations of this question.

One is pairwise sum with overlap 1. Examples (inclusive of some given answers):

```
ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, list]
Plus @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
Partition[list, 2, 1].{1, 1}
{1, 1}.{Most@list, Rest@list}
MovingMap[Total, list, 1]
```

all yielding {6, 9, 12, 14, 10}

The other interpretation as per MichaelE2 cumulative sum,e.g.:

```
FoldList[Plus, list]
Accumulate[list]
```

yielding: {2, 6, 11, 18, 25, 28}

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Plus[Prepend[list, 0], Append[list, 0]][[2 ;; -2]]
```

And inspired by ubpdqn:

```
Plus[Rest[list], Most[list]]
```

Which is the fastest I can find. I also observed speed differences if the list contains pure Integers or Reals.

**Addition**

Random integers gives this timing:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 100000];
{RepeatedTiming[Plus[Prepend[list, 0], Append[list, 0]][[2 ;; -2]];], 
  RepeatedTiming[Plus[Rest[list], Most[list]];], 
  RepeatedTiming[ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, list];], 
  RepeatedTiming[Plus @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1];], 
  RepeatedTiming[Partition[list, 2, 1].{1, 1};], 
  RepeatedTiming[{1, 1}.{Most@list, Rest@list};], 
  RepeatedTiming[MovingMap[Total, list, 1];]}[[All, 1]]
```

{0.00043, 0.000137, 0.000737, 0.0317, 0.0055, 0.0015, 0.0394}

Random reals gives this timing:

```
list = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 100000];
{RepeatedTiming[Plus[Prepend[list, 0], Append[list, 0]][[2 ;; -2]];], 
  RepeatedTiming[Plus[Rest[list], Most[list]];], 
  RepeatedTiming[ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, list];], 
  RepeatedTiming[Plus @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1];], 
  RepeatedTiming[Partition[list, 2, 1].{1, 1};], 
  RepeatedTiming[{1, 1}.{Most@list, Rest@list};], 
  RepeatedTiming[MovingMap[Total, list, 1];]}[[All, 1]]
```

{0.0298, 0.00014, 0.00144, 0.040, 0.00430, 0.00089, 0.052}

10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2015)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3};

diff = Differences[list];

FoldList[Plus, First[list], diff]
```

> {2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 3}